# SSHFS - File time not updating

Tags: apache2, sshfs

I have an apache webserver that has the code mounted through SSHFS. When I make a change to a file on the remote computer, the webserver does not show the change. If I interact with the file in any way, such as `cat` or `vim` and do not make any changes, then the webserver will show the change correctly and the file modification time updates.

Is there a way to get the file modification time to update correctly, or perhaps I need to modify apache in some way so that it definitely reads the files (perhaps there is some sort of cache based on times that it uses which I could disable)?

Comment: Where are you `cat`ing from? What happens if you write wait a minute, then try to access the page?

Comment: The manual for sshfs mentions some caches, you can change the time-outs on them.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh whether this helps.

Comment: @richard You were right about the cache. If you add `-o cache=no` to the sshfs command then the changes are immediate. If you put that in an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual for sshfs mentions some caches, you can change the time-outs on them.

Try `-o cache=no`. If that works, then consider setting the time-out to some low number.